# Getting the results of two or more columns to change another calculated column

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

I have searched and searched the web for the answer but nothing I try seems to work in these SharePoint calculated columns, basically, I have a column called Email Sign Off and another called Equipment Sign Off, they are both Yes / No Columns. User Status (calculated column where the results will appear)

what I want to happen is if both columns are empty the User status to say "Not Started"
When either Email Sign Off or Equipment Sign Off are True the User Status to say "In Progress"
if both columns are True then the User Status to say "Complete"

I have tried several code examples, after trying my own but the results do not come out as they are meant to or SharePoint tells me the code is wrong.
From my limited programming knowledge I'm used to using ELSE, &&, OR but these do not seem to work even though others have given examples including AND, OR, but apparently ELSE doesn't exist.

```
=IF([Email Sign Off]=TRUE,IF([Equipment Sign off]=FALSE,"In Progess",IF([Email Sign Off]=FALSE,IF([Equipment Sign off]=TRUE,"In Progess 2",IF([Email Sign Off],[Equipment Sign off]=TRUE,"Complete")))))
```

[image: Results to the code above]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this formula:

```
=IF(AND([Email Sign Off], [Equipment Sign off]), "Complete", IF(AND(NOT([Email Sign Off]), NOT([Equipment Sign off])), "Not Started", "In Progress"))
```

---

**Note**:

1. Sometimes comma(`,`) does not work in formula (I am not sure but it is based on something language or regional settings on your site). So in that case use semicolon(`;`) instead of comma(`,`).

**Output**:

[image]

Comment: Hi and thank you for attempting to help but even though the code was excepted, the desired results did not appear

Comment: Try using updated formula in above answer.

Comment: for some reason every version works except if Email Sign Off is TRUE and Equipment Sign Off is FALSE then it displays as complete.

Comment: Can you confirm if Equipment Sign Off is actually FALSE or just "empty"? Try adding filter on this column to check if there are any empty values.

Comment: I'm using a simple Yes / No column with the default set to No

Comment: If you have created a column after adding some list items, older list items will have empty value for Yes/No column. As suggested above, can you check once if the column has any empty entries?

Comment: Hi Thank you that worked, i went through the rows with existing data and ticked all the boxes and then unchecked the ones to see the results and now it's working as you described